# Where can I find the current value of a position in the Avaloq Banking Suite tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, avaloq-script

I'm looking for the table that shows the value of a position on a specific day, or at the very least, just the current value of the position without having to search through the doc_meta_type tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pos_serpil is the table you are looking for, it contains the values of the positions updated twice a day. It is also historical, so if you search using timestamp, you can return the value of the position for a specific date.

Answer (score 1):

If you want at the very least, just the current value of the position. This shortcut query will do the work.

select script#.eval_expr('obj_pos(x).qty') from dual;

Where x is the position id. Make sure that the session is open before running the query. (exec session#.open_session;)